# Can I use #8 copper to replace a #6 ground wire?

Tags: electrical

I need to replace the ground wire that runs from the panel to the rod embedded in earth. it looks like the existing wire is 6 g. i'm having trouble finding that gauge and wonder if I can use 8 gauge instead.

Comment: I would stick with #6, either with green insulation or bare copper. This is standard for residential services, at least in my country.

Comment: How many amps of electrical service do you have?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without specific information about your electrical system. As it is, it's a matter of opinion (or guesswork), and therefore off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the local code. Instead of dropping to 8 you could go bigger, assuming 6 gauge was to code in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is a good idea for a DIY to replace a large conductor with a smaller conductor. Since it was probably installed by skilled labor who have experience in such things and there are many reasons why they did what they did. See Chris Taylor's comment.

Also I am having a problem understanding why it would be hard to find a supplier who doesn't stock both a #8 and a #6 solid wire ground conductor since both are common and cost is nominal. In fact I would believe that most suppliers would rather stock a #6 than a #8, since a #6 covers more situations than a #8. Try looking at any big box or local hardware store and see if the can supply you with the same size conductor.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, you should be able to find 6AWG very easily.

In general, you can't replace a wire with a smaller wire unless you're certain that the smaller wire satisfies the code requirements.

There are requirements in NEC Table 250.66 that stipulate minimum size for the grounding electrode conductor (GEC) based on the size of the service conductors.  The table shows that #8 is too small if your service conductors are larger than #2.

Also NEC article 250.64(B) requires that if the GEC is smaller than #6, it must be in conduit or cable armor for protection.

So if your service conductors are #2 or smaller and the GEC is in conduit, you can use #8.

Be careful when working on the GEC.  There are additional rules that apply, and there can be unexpected hazards - do not assume that wire can't zap you.

Comment: Actually, the more common approach for protecting GECs and bonding conductors is cable armor, using something called a Bare Armored Ground cable.  Using metal conduit for protecting a GEC requires bonding the conduit to the wire to avoid choke effects that would limit current flow through the GEC.